# Add a block to product page if the product has an attribute set to specific value

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, blocks, template

I have a custom attribute that can be Yes or No. If a product has this attribute set to Yes then in product page view I want to display a block below "Add to Cart" button.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

and add code there.

```
if($product->getAttributeCode()){
     echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Yourblock');
}
```